# Query fieldCondition for custom content type

Tags: 7, database

I am attempting to query a custom content type called players (machine name) in a Drupal 7 module and it seemed to be working fine up until an hour ago. Nothing has changed on my side but now the 'Select' works ( with no fieldCondition, but when I add a fieldCondition I am getting empty results.

Here is my query:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'players')
  ->fieldCondition('field_email_address', 'value', $email_address)
  ->fieldCondition('field_password', 'value', $password)
  ->range(0, 1);

$results = $query->execute();
```

I have verified and reverified the bundle name, each machine name for the fields, and the values being passed in, but when I dump and die the query results, they come up empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `, '='` from the `field_email_address` fieldCondition?

Comment: I tried that still didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the [Email field](https://www.drupal.org/project/email) module, the column name is `email`, rather than `value`.

If that's the case, just change that line to:

```
->fieldCondition('field_email_address', 'email', $email_address, '=')
```

You may need to make a similar change for the password field, depending on what type it is. The easiest way to check for valid column names is in the .install file of the module that provides it, within its implementation of [`hook_field_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7.x).

Comment: It's a custom content type with a text field called field_email_address

Comment: In that case your original code was fine, and the problem must simply be that the strings don’t match

Answer (score 0):

You may need to actually execute the query:

```
$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'players')
  ->fieldCondition('field_email_address', 'value', $email_address, '=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_password', 'value', $password)
  ->range(0, 1);

$results = $query->execute();
```

Comment: I do execute the query but the results are empty if you add the fieldCondition but not if you remove it.

Comment: Have you tried just one of the `fieldConditions` at a time to see if one of them breaks it but the other one works? Try with and without the `range` as well. Maybe there's an issue with your `$email_address` or `$password` variables.

Comment: It seems like a permission issue. When I am logged in as admin it works, when I am not, I cannot added the fieldConditions to the query. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for some stupid reason you can query a whole database as an unauthenticated user but not with a where clause so you need to add ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)) before the ->range(0,1). Hope this helps someone else.